# Empty text template for WPF ComboBox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How would I apply "an empty text" template for WPF `ComboBox`?

```
<ComboBox 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}"
          DisplayMemberPath="CroppedMessage"
          Name="Messages"
          Width="150" Margin="0,4,4,4">
</ComboBox>
```

I use the above code to display a `ComboBox` with a few messages. Now, when the application starts there's no item chosen by default, and if so, I want to display a custom text on the `ComboBox`. I think I would need some kind of template with a trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}"
          DisplayMemberPath="CroppedMessage"
          Name="Messages"
          Width="150"
          Margin="0,4,4,4"
          IsEditable="True"
          Text="select" />
```

Comment: It's nice, but I don't want it to be editable :). Can I have the same behavior except without editing capabilities?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}"
          DisplayMemberPath="CroppedMessage"
          Name="Messages"
          Width="150"
          Margin="0,4,4,4"
          IsEditable="True"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          Text="Select"/>
```